# e2e testing a microservice in Nest

Tags: typescript, microservices, e2e-testing, nestjs

I'm attempting to write e2e tests for a microservice in Nest.  I think I've got my ProxyClient created properly in order to do requests to the service.

What I'm trying to do in my tests:

1. Create a proxy client
2. Send a message using that client
3. Have them message be picked up by the service
4. Return the result of the message processing done by the service

Here's what I have so far...it seems like it's close but I keep seeing this when I run my tests.

> Expected: true, 
>       Received: {"_isScalar": false, "operator": {"concurrent": Infinity, "project": [Function anonymous]}, "source": {"_isScalar": false, "_subscribe": [Function anonymous]}}

```
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ClientsModule, Transport, ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { HeartbeatModule } from './../src/heartbeat.module';
import { HeartbeatService } from './../src/heartbeat.service';


describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app;
  let client: ClientProxy;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [HeartbeatModule, ClientsModule.register([{ name: 'HEARTBEAT_SERVICE', transport: Transport.TCP }])],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();

    client = app.get('HEARTBEAT_SERVICE');
    await client.connect();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await client.close();
  });

  it('sends a level 1 heartbeat message to the HeartbeatService', async () => {
    const response = client.send({"cmd": "heartbeat"}, {"type": 1});

    expect(response).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Noticed this:HeartbeatController (e2e) › sends a level 1 heartbeat message to the HeartbeatService

    connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so I was missing a few things from beforeEach...here is the working code...

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ClientsModule, Transport, ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { HeartbeatModule } from './../src/heartbeat.module';
import { HeartbeatService } from './../src/heartbeat.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

describe('HeartbeatController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let client: ClientProxy;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HeartbeatModule,
        ClientsModule.register([
          { name: 'HEARTBEAT_SERVICE', transport: Transport.TCP },
        ]),
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

    app.connectMicroservice({
      transport: Transport.TCP,
    });

    await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
    await app.init();

    client = app.get('HEARTBEAT_SERVICE');
    await client.connect();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
    client.close();
  });

  it('sends a level 1 heartbeat message to the HeartbeatService', done => {
    const response: Observable<any> = client.send(
      { cmd: 'heartbeat' },
      { type: 1 },
    );

    response.subscribe(json => {
      expect(Date.parse(json.now)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(new Date().getTime());
      expect(json.originalRequest.type).toBe(1);

      done();
    });
  });

  it('sends a level 2 heartbeat message to the HeartbeatService', done => {
    const requestJson = {
      type: 2,
      startTime: 12345,
      endTime: 67890,
      messagesSent: 22,
    };
    const response: Observable<any> = client.send(
      { cmd: 'heartbeat' },
      requestJson,
    );

    response.subscribe(json => {
      expect(Date.parse(json.now)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(new Date().getTime());
      expect(json.messagesReceived).toBe(22);
      expect(json.originalRequest.type).toBe(2);
      expect(json.originalRequest.startTime).toBe(12345);
      expect(json.originalRequest.endTime).toBe(67890);
      expect(json.originalRequest.messagesSent).toBe(22);

      done();
    });
  });

});
```

I'm getting a jest error "Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.".  I'll probably ignore it but am open to any ideas as to how to fix it :)

**EDIT:** Thanks Jay McDoniel, I updated my answer with the completed working code.

Comment: Oh! You can fix the did not exit error by adding a callback to your observable and calling it. So on you `it` line the second parameter should be `(done)` and after all your assertions you should call `done()`. You should also look into using an observer instead of callbacks for your observables as callbacks will be deprecated in the future. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/jmcdo29/f9d4d3effc2d55996341ce18fe0cb6d3) that kind of goes over it. I still need to update it more

Comment: instead of done you could also make the function `async` and use `await`
`const json = response.toPromise()`
that way you don't need a `done`

like
`it("{cmd: 'sum'}", async () => {
        const result = await client.send({cmd: 'sum'}, [1, 2, 3]).toPromise();
        expect(result).toEqual(6);
    });`